# REST GET request: Is it fine to expect query string parameter back in response so as to avoid computation on client side

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-design

We have an api that gives valuation of electronic item based on its manufacturer, year of manufacturing, city of purchase.

In the response we get two prices, bad price (in case product has little damages) and good price (in case product is almost new). We show these two prices along with details of original electronic item in new screen like:

Original item manufacturer, year of manufacturing, city of purchase.

AND bad price and good price.

We have this input form where user fills details, click on "Get Valuation button". Then we hit our valuation API, that gives us back the results.

Now, we have two choices for response of valution API:

```
1. Keep only bad price and good price in response AND extract Original item manufacturer, year of manufacturing, city of purchase from input query string to API from client.
```

Pro of this approach: Simple and neat. Looks obvious.

Con: But problem is that each client (desk,mobile,android,ios) needs to pick user input and use them in output screen.

```
2. Keep bad price, good price,Original item manufacturer, year of manufacturing, city of purchase in response of API.
```

Pro: No need to pick info from api inputs and pass it to output screen. The response for 2nd screen is complete.

Con: The client expects server to send back the data it already had.

Which is better approach? Which one should we choose?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I would add some custom headers to the response that will contain the data that client needs for  computation. For example in case of a get request where I support paging I would add a pagination header to the response something like this:

```
public static class ApiExtensions
{
    #region Fields

    private static string X_PAGINATION_HEADER = "X-Pagination";

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a header to the current response with the pagination data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="headers">Current response header collection</param>
    /// <param name="query">Query executed</param>
    /// <param name="queryResult">Query result</param>
    /// <param name="urlHelper">Url helper to create next/previous links</param>
    /// <param name="routeName">Current executing route</param>
    /// <returns>Current response headers with pagination data</returns>
    public static NameValueCollection AddPaginationHeader(this NameValueCollection headers, IQuery query, IQueryResult queryResult, UrlHelper urlHelper, string routeName)
    {
        dynamic dQuery = query;
        dynamic dResult = queryResult;
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)dResult.TotalCount / dQuery.PageSize);
        var previousLink = (dQuery.Page > 1) ? urlHelper.Link(routeName, new
        {
            sortParams = dQuery.SortParams,
            page = (dQuery.Page - 1),
            pageSize = dQuery.PageSize,
            userId = dQuery.UserId
        }) : "";


        var nextLink = (dQuery.Page < totalPages) ? urlHelper.Link(routeName, new
        {
            sortParams = dQuery.SortParams,
            page = (dQuery.Page + 1),
            pageSize = dQuery.PageSize,
            userId = dQuery.UserId
        }) : "";

        var paginationHeader = new
        {
            currentPage = dQuery.Page,
            pageSize = dQuery.PageSize,
            totalPages = totalPages,
            nextLink = nextLink,
            previousLink = previousLink
        };

        headers.Add(X_PAGINATION_HEADER, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));
        return headers;
    }
}
```

And then call this extension method in my controller before returning the response:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AddPaginationHeader(query, result, new UrlHelper(Request), "datalist");
            return Ok(result);
```